# Best way of syncing phone book contacts with my app on updates deletes and inserts

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, synchronization

I am developing an app on android.I want to sync the phone book contacts with my app every time there is an insert,delete or an update.I have seen syncing on whatsapp is really fast.How should i acheive that much speed.

I have used contentResolver.registerContentObserver() for changes.But it fires only changes to the table even if i use row uri for data.Is there a way that it gives me the exact row where the changes have occurred so that i could reflect them in my app.

Comment: make your app use the same database, the contentprovider containing the contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Daniel.
I made my app use the same database, the contentprovider containing the contacts. This solved my problem.